# Fiber texture load fails with error: A component suspended while responding to synchronous input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, fibers

I'm trying to load a texture using textureloader:

`const texture = useLoader(TextureLoader, '/textures/texture.png')`

react gives me an error:

> ERROR
> A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.

My dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.58.4",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.12.0",
    "@react-three/postprocessing": "^2.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "three": "^0.150.1"
  },
```

importing a texture using drei(useTexture) gives the same error.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved by wrapping the component that calls `useLoader()` in `<Suspense>` component, like this:

```
import { Suspense } from 'react';

<Suspense fallback={<div>Wait...</div>}>
   <MyComponentThatCallsUseLoader/>
</Suspense>
```

While the textures are loading, the fallback component is rendered instead of the children of `<Suspense>`.